# Como hago la suma y la resta de dos tablas en un mismo query

Tags: sql

Tengo 3 tablas y quiero obtener la suma de los renglones por producto

```
SELECT (SUM(a.cantidad) - SUM(b.cantidad)) as total, p.nombre FROM producto p
JOIN alta a ON p.id = a.id_producto
JOIN baja b ON p.id = b.id_producto
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id
```

El resultado debería ser 45 (50 (la suma de alta)  menos 5 (la suma de baja)) pero me da 80 el resultado lo multiplica por el numero de renglones de la otra tabla 50 * 2 y 5 * 4

Como puedo hacer el query para un resultado correcto ya traté de agrupar de varias formas pero aún no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sé bien si `baja` y `alta` son una tabla c/u o es la misma tabla pero con alguna condición distingues los renglones; pero asumiendo son dos tablas te sugiero subquery en el `JOIN` y obtener un renglón por cada `id_producto`; a manera de ejemplo:

```
SELECT (a.cantidad - b.cantidad) as total, p.nombre FROM producto p
JOIN (
   SELECT id_producto, SUM(cantidad ) as cantidad 
   FROM
      alta 
   GROUP by id_producto
) a ON p.id = a.id_producto
JOIN (
   SELECT id_producto, SUM(cantidad ) as cantidad 
   FROM
      baja 
   GROUP by id_producto
) b ON p.id = b.id_producto
WHERE p.id = 1
/* Esto ya no será necesario   GROUP BY p.id */
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.